# Order of Data Type Modifiers in C++

Tags: c++, types, modifier

In C++, why does `int long long unsigned x;` not produce any syntax error because `unsigned` and `long long` are modifiers which must be written before the data type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modifiers can come in any order before or after the type. `int long unsigned`, `long int unsigned`, `unsigned int long`, `int unsigned long`, `long unsigned int`, `unsigned long int` are all equivalent.

Answer (score 5):

> modifiers and must be written before the data type?

**No**

According to [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types):

> ## Modifiers
>
> Modifies the integer type. **Can be mixed in any order**. Only one of each
>   group can be present in type name.

Therefore, you don't get any syntax errors when you do so but it will cause readability issues.